# django tastypie get related column total amount

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

Given the below JSON result from tastypie, I would like to create a new value at check.payments_total which is equal to the total amount of the payments (in this case, 44.00). Any clue on how to do this? I'm completely stumped. payments is a joined foreign key to the check table.

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "check": {
            "id": "58a81b36-1ea6-403b-9902-a50cbd13cf2e",
            "number": 2,
            "payments": [
                {
                    "amount": "5.00",
                },
                {
                    "amount": "39.00",
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Do you want total for payments in the response or for all payments in the DB?

Comment: I would guess: for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for the response, then you could override the following method in your resource (the snippet is from `tastypie.resources.Resource`):

```
def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
    """
    A hook to alter list data just before it gets serialized & sent to the user.

    Useful for restructuring/renaming aspects of the what's going to be
    sent.

    Should accommodate for a list of objects, generally also including
    meta data.
    """
    return data
```

just include something like (not tested, consider to be pseudo-code):

```
 total_amount = 0.0
 for object in data[ 'objects' ]:
     total_amount += object[ 'amount' ]

 return { 'objects' : data[ 'objects' ], 'total_amount' : total_amount }
```

and you should be done.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. I'll try to implement this asap and let you know how it goes.